# How to adjust camera parameters for a video recording in cwac-camera?

Tags: android, video, orientation, commonsware-cwac

My app has a fixed UI orientation. Because of that, when a video is recorded, it always has the same orientation embedded in the video. However, I would like to set the orientation to what the sensors tell me instead of the  `getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();`

Here are some of my findings:

1. There is no `adjustPictureParamaters()` method (like there is for the pictures) on the CameraHost that would update the video recording parameters
2. Extending and overriding methods on the CameraView is not possible because some of the methods are private.
3. I could create my own custom branch of the cwac code and update the logic but I really don't want to maintain a separate branch just for something minor like this.
4. Reprocessing the video and updating orientation after it's recorded takes some extra time.

For now I will probably go with #4. But is there a better solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is no adjustPictureParamaters() method (like there is for the pictures) on the CameraHost that would update the video recording parameters

There is no way to update the video recording parameters in the way that you seek AFAIK. Video recording, more so than still picture recording, is up to the device, not us.

> Extending and overriding methods on the CameraView is not possible because some of the methods are private.

Moreover, none of them would help you in this case.

> I could create my own custom branch of the cwac code and update the logic but I really don't want to maintain a separate branch just for something minor like this.

Moreover, none of that would help you in this case.

> Reprocessing the video and updating orientation after it's recorded takes some extra time.

That is the only option that I know of.

Comment: do you have a suggestion for post-processing a video?  a lib?  something already in Android?

Comment: @browep: There is nothing really for video processing in Android proper. Other than `ffmpeg`, I am not aware of other video processing code available for Android, though there certainly could be some, as I have never gone looking for any.